# PHP Regular Expression: string from inside brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have a string:

```
$a = "Name[value]";
```

How do I get the 'Name' and 'value' portions of string into variables from this string?  I'm not that great at regular expressions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

so this should do the trick for you:

```
(.*)\[(.*)\]
```

This is the PHP syntax:

```
<?php
$subject = "Name[value]";
$pattern = '/(.*)\[(.*)\]/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name[value]
    [1] => Name
    [2] => value
)
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/**
 * Regex Quick Extraction - ignore $matches[0];
 */

$a = "Name[value]";

preg_match('/([^\]]*)\[([^\]]*)\]/',$a,$matches);

if(count($matches) > 0) {
    print_r($matches);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 <?php
$a = "Name[value]";
preg_match('/(?<name>.*?)\[(?<value>.*[^\]]+)/', $a, $matched); 
 echo '<pre>'; 
 print_r($matched);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Name[value
    [name] => Name
    [1] => Name
    [value] => value
    [2] => value
)
```