# Geting two matches in a string using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex

My string:

```
fields[name_1]
```

I want to get `fields` and `name_1` using regex.

I'm know about `preg_match_all()`, but I'm not friends with regular expressions.

Comment: Such a banal question around Regular Expressions, gets some up-voted answers. Something's wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935717/php-regular-expression-string-from-inside-brackets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be used for direct match:

```
$string = 'fields[name_1]';

preg_match('/(.+)\[(.+)\]/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

You get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fields[name_1]
    [1] => fields
    [2] => name_1
)
```

So, `$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]` are what you needed.

---

Still I am unclear about your exact need!

---

Here are the explanation for the Regex:

1. https://regex101.com/r/PcJzQL/3
2. http://www.phpliveregex.com/
3. https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html

Comment: thx. You were the first, so your answer will be marked as true.

Comment: You might want to use `+` instead of `*`. Currently your regex will match a simple `[]` with both groups empty. [Compare here](https://regex101.com/r/PcJzQL/2). I know you are not using global flag, but if there were more matches in string it would be safer to use the plus sign for quantifier.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko - you might want to consider my comment above.

Comment: @Asunez Thanks modified!

Answer (score 2):

THere are uncounted examples for this alone here on SO. A simple search would have shown you what you need. Anyway, to get you going:

```
<?php
$subject = 'fields[name_1]';
preg_match('/^(.+)\[(.+)]$/', $subject, $tokens);
print_r($tokens);
```

The output of that obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => fields[name_1]
    [1] => fields
    [2] => name_1
)
```

Comment: thx. My English is too bad for right search this exaples, sorry.

Comment: @StanislavBelichenko Then start reading the official documentation of the php functions you want to use. They are of good quality, come with helpful examples and are translated in many languages: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: You are right, I did not think at all that there could be a similar example.

Comment: If you knew that there are thousands of examples around this topic on SO then wouldn't it be better if you voted this question to be closed as a duplicate instead of posting an answer?